# Pandoc: how split title going from html to docx

Tags: html, docx, pandoc

In a HTML document that I need to convert to DOCX I have a long title that I want to split into two lines in the resulting DOCX. But if I put a `<br>` in the `<title>` the text after the break disappears. To reproduce:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Scientist and father: <br>my journey from ignorance to Montessori enthusiasm</title>
</head><body>
<p>Bla bla bla.</p>
</body></html>
```

Process it as: `pandoc split.html -o split.docx`

If you remove the `<br>` the title appears correctly on one line. Yes, I know that a break in title in HTML does not make much sense, but this is only an intermediate file to generate the DOCX.

Comment: Have you tried `\v` instead of `<br>`?

Comment: Yes, but Word complains and at the end ignore it.

Comment: What about `<br />`?

Comment: Tried also, no way.